# Is there an easy way under Linux to implement a function that acts like GC.GetTotalMemory in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, linux, mono

[MSDN Link: GC.GetTotalMemory Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx)

I don't need the garbage collection part. I only need to know the number of bytes currently 
thought to be allocated. Is there an easy way to do so under Linux?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. What would be analogous under Linux where there typically is no such thing as "managed memory"? If you want the total amount of memory obtained from `malloc` and friends, your allocator likely has such functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`getrusage(2,3p)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage).

Answer (score 0):

You can always parse the  `/proc/self/maps` or `/proc/self/status` files (and other files under `/proc`) from inside your application (you'll get more information than with just [getrusage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage) syscall).

If you used the [Boehm garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/), it gives you `GC_get_heap_size`, `GC_get_total_bytes` ... functions.

And GNU libc has [mallinfo](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Statistics-of-Malloc.html#Statistics-of-Malloc)

I cannot understand why your question is tagged *C#* ; on Linux that means [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/).